# How to update Excel Pivot filters?

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

When I have updated information in a Pivot table I can click "Refresh" and it will update the data **within** the pivot chart. However, there seems to be a bug where it does not update the **filter values** in the pivot filter.

[image]

Here is a brief video showing a way to reproduce this: https://gyazo.com/2a60fe4d01d171f94a284e7d3ead69e1. How do I fix this, or do I literally have to remove the filter in the pivot and re-add (that's not an option for me though since I have filters already added in a template!

Comment: It is not updating may be because of cache memory what you can do is right click on the pivot table options data tab and change the number of items to retain per field to none, now if you refresh it will work, i believe.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya thanks, that worked. Want to add that as an answer and I'll accept that?

Comment: just posted in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know generally it was not updating because of cache memory so the workaround is to right click on the `Pivot Table Options` --> `Data Tab` and *change* the **number of items** to retain per field to **none**, now if the pivot table is refreshed it will work certainly.

---

Answer (score -1):

Right-click the pivot table, and select Refresh.

Comment: did you watch the video? That's the first thing I did in the video.